# How to sort an array based on the occurrences of the elements in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have got an array

`string [] country = {"IND", "RSA", "NZ", "AUS", "WI", "SL", "ENG", "BAN"};`

I have a string

`downloadString = "The match between India (IND) and Australia (AUS) is into its exciting phase. South Africa (RSA) won the match against England (ENG) "`

So I am trying to find which of the array elements are present in the string. I am able to find that `IND` , `RSA`, `AUS` and `ENG` are present in the string. However, I am unable to order them according to their occurrence in the string. So right now the output which I get is

`IND, RSA, AUS, ENG`

Whereas, what I really need is

`IND, AUS, RSA, ENG`

How can I do that?

Comment: What are you using to get them?

Comment: Post your code and be more clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve and what have you done till now. This is a simple problem with number of ways to achieve the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this concisely with a Linq query (I've renamed your original array to `countries`):

```
var result = countries.Select(country => new { country, 
                                               index = downloadString.IndexOf(country)})
                      .Where(pair => pair.index >= 0)
                      .OrderBy(pair => pair.index)
                      .Select(pair => pair.country)
                      .ToArray();
```

The result is `IND, AUS, RSA, ENG`.

Comment: This one will also have performance issue, finding index of every country in the list it has the order of n^x

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The running time of this algorithm will be O(n * l), where l is the length of the string. What is this `x` that you are referring to and how did you arrive at the conclusion that the running time is n^x? Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @JLRishe x refers to number of times it goes through the string to find an index, here it would be number of element in the Countries array. This is the case of linear search where it search from the beginning for every element, that's why O(n^x), it will not be fetching all the indexes in one go as you have suggested, Select will process each element separately, it would  not be O(n*l). For a very long string or long array, search solutions are bound to be inefficient. Linq is not a magic wand it just makes things more readable and concise, it does the same job as foreach

Comment: @MrinalKamboj This example will go through the string exactly `n` times (where `n` is the size of the `countries` array). If the length of the string is `l`, then the running time of the first `Select()` is proportional to `n * l`. This algorithm does not have an exponential running time.

Comment: @JLRishe correct my mistake, but still for a very long string of length l it would not be a good approach, suppose we are searching from a document of few MB. In any case other Linq queries like Where, Select will make sure that we go the exponential way, it will become O(n^4). I would prefer a dictionary to make things quicker

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The running time will not be O(n^4), and as I already said, if you have a better solution, I am eager to see it.

Comment: @JLRishe I am working on one using Dictionary, it will not be concise as yours, since it does not use Linq, all I am trying to figure out is avoid Linear search, make the search O(1) from O(n).
BTW this 4 comes from the concatenated Linq queries Select, Where, Select, it is not same as x suggested earlier

Comment: @JLRishe Just pasted a solution, using Dictionary, which may optimize the overall working / search for a complex solution if required

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The impact of the successive Linq operations is additive, not multiplicative. The total running time is `O(n * l + n + n log n + n + n)`. Simplifying this leaves `O(n * l)`. See for yourself: http://ideone.com/LGHdHj These results show that the running time is actually better than `n * l`, as it does not increase proportionally to the length of the string.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks for providing a good example, this has helped me a lot in understanding the actual working, so as you say its like multiple serial for loops not concatenated for loops. I think you can use Stopwatch to be more precise for timing, DateTime is not very precise. I am running few more tests using your code

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use regex with the following pattern:

```
\b(IND|RSA|NZ|AUS|WI|SL|ENG|BAN)\b
```

### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/U6Vd29jGpI)

**Sample Code:** (untested)

```
MatchCollection matches= System.Text.RegularExpresssion.Regex.Matches(yourStringSample, patternHere);

for each (Match m in matches)
{
   Debug.Print(m.ToString())
}
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment below, I should highlight that the regex pattern should build using similar code like below: (as suggested by JLRishe)

```
string pattern = "(" + string.Join("|", country.Select(c => Regex.Escape(c))) + ")"
```

Comment: Nice solution. And this has the added benefit of taking duplicate occurrences into account (if that is what OP wants). You might want to provide an example of how to build that regex dynamically: `"(" + string.Join("|", country.Select(c => Regex.Escape(c))) + ")"`.

Comment: @JLRishe, yes thanks for highlighting it, I forget to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the string and keep the position of the found item, then sort them according to their position in string. You may need an array of a structure to keep both the label and position instead of the country array!